# How to print Dag failure log inside the on_failure_callback callback method

Tags: python, airflow

Here is my dag code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack import BaseHook
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookHook
import requests
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException

SLACK_CONN_ID = 'slack'

def main():
    try:
        url=""
        response = requests.heads(url)
        status_code = response.status_code
    except AirflowException as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        raise


def task_success_slack_alert(context):
    context = context.get('dag_run').conf
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    channel = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).login

    slack_msg = '''
        :white_check_mark: Task Succeeded! 
        *Task*: "decide"  
        *Dag*: "Reaper_heart_bit"
        *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
        *Log Url*: {log_url} 
    '''.format(
        task="decide",
        dag="Reaper_heart_bit",
        exec_date=context.get("execution_date"),
        log_url="",
    )

    slack_hook = SlackWebhookHook(webhook_token=slack_webhook_token, message=slack_msg, channel=channel, username="airflow")
    return slack_hook.execute()

def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    context = context.get('dag_run').conf
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    channel = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).login
    execution_date = context.get("execution_date")
    error_message = context.get('exception')
    task_log ="" #i want to get aidrflow dag log and assign to task_log
    slack_msg = '''
        :rotating_light: Task Failed. 
        *Task*: "decide"  
        *Dag*: "Reaper_heart_bit"
        *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
        *Log Url*: {log_url} 
         *Error Message*: {error_message}
         *Airflow Log*: {task_log}
    '''.format(
        task="decide",
        dag="Reaper_heart_bit",
        exec_date=context.get("execution_date"),
        log_url="",
        error_message=error_message,
        task_log=task_log
    )

    slack_hook = SlackWebhookHook(webhook_token=slack_webhook_token, message=slack_msg, channel=channel, username="airflow")
    return slack_hook.execute()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'pradip',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 9, 23),
    'email': ["pradip@gmail.com"],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    "on_failure_callback": task_fail_slack_alert,
    "on_success_callback": task_success_slack_alert
}


dag = DAG(
    'Reaper_heart_bit',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 23),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval="@daily",  # Change this to your desired schedule interval
)

decide_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="decide",
    python_callable=main,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
decide_task
```

[image]

I need assistance in extracting the error logs highlighted in the red box from the above image and passing them to the 'task_log' parameter of the **'task_fail_slack_alert(context)'** function. Can anyone guide how to accomplish this?

**I attempted to retrieve the log using 'context.get('task_instance').log', but the response I received was 'None'.**